# Devise Not found Authentication passthru error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Though devise is configured with method post for omniauth_authorize_path

Code from devise gem app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb

```
<% if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
   <% resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), method: :post %><br />
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Still getting not found Authentication passthru error

Omniauth version - 2.0.4

Devise version - 4.8.0